# More than one path in a directed graph?

Tags: graph, path, routes, dijkstra

I want to start building an app for public transport. I know I should use Dijkstra as the algorithm to find the shortest path between two points.

How can I get more than one path? I would like to give the user at least 3 or 4 options, not only the best route. The reason is that I want to include more variables, time, cost and bus capacity.

Is there any algorithm that could help me to do this? Or naively I was thinking I should modify Dijkstra to give me more than one path.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [K shortest path routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing), a generalization of dijkstra.

Comment: Will have a look. Thanks mate.